# Could someone tell me what could "dolce fiore" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, translation, meaning

I'm looking for help to find out the meaning of a phrase I was told. Maybe someone could explain me what could "dolce fiore" mean? An Italian friend (and only a friend) of mine has said it to me, but yet the language is a bit difficult for me to understand every expression. He said that these kind of expressions are used when somebody "si vuole bene". So, was this something he meant in a very sweet friendly way or, unfortunately, something more than friendly?:(
Thank You so much in advance.

Comment: It just means *sweet flower*. The exact meaning depends on context, but it is a positive expression. Whether it indicates fraternal love or romantic love is for you to decide.

Answer (score 4):

Literally the meaning is *sweet flower*, but it's the kind of thing you say to a lover. E.g. [here](http://wikitesti.com/dolce_fiore/).

I'd go with *somewhat more than friendly*, or maybe *friend with hopes*.

Comment: Another citation from the first verse of a popular song can be found here, http://wikitesti.com/far_lamore_con_te/ and this too suggests a more than friendly hope... Anyway this expression can certainly be used in a friendly and fraternal context and the exact meaning can be determined only by other signals.